# Java DecimalFormat - Using Integers

Tags: java

I have a currency in pennies, as an integer (ex: `1234`). I need the output to be: `$12.34`. We are not allowed to use doubles or floats on this assignment, only Integers.

Here is what I have:

```
totalChange = 1234;
DecimalFormat ourFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");
String totalString = ourFormat.format(totalChange);
System.out.println("Your change of " + totalString + " is as follows:");
```

I would assume that the DecimalFormat would go from right to left, assigning `34` to be after the decimal point, and the `12` should be placed before.

I'm getting an output of `Your change of $1234.00 is as follows:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format will not artificially introduce decimal places not present in the input.

You could try converting to dollars and cents first, then combining the two with '.'

```
int dollars = totalChange / 100;
int cents = totalChange % 100;
```

**Hint** (Based on comment from @DanielFischer)

Cents can be 1 or 2 digits, but you probably want to output them always as 2 digits.

Comment: So you're saying to split up the dollars and cents, and do something like: `"$ + dollars + "." + cents"`?

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll implement it, then mark yours as correct. Thank you sir.

Comment: Well, the problem topic was a bit larger than this, but it mentioned not using them. Personally I would rather just use the doubles, but if we're not allowed, we're not allowed. Appreciate it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That's a valid test to ensure the formatting is correct :-)

Comment: Thanks, just thought of this and actually applied a DecimalFormat to the change with `"00"`. So this turns 5 into 05.

Comment: @ardavis Yes, that's exactly what I was getting at.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is probably trying to teach you about integer division and modulus.

When you divide integers, the remainder is completely discarded, so you need to use the modulo operator if you want that information.  The modulo operator (%) gives you only the remainder from division.  For example 5 / 3 = 1 and 5 % 3 = 2.

These operations lend themselves very nicely to your problem.

Say I want to figure out how many nickels and pennies I need to make exact change for some amount.

```
int totalChange = 27; //I have 27¢
int nickels = totalChange / 5; //This gives 5 and discards the remainder
int pennies = totalChange % 5; //This gives 2, the remainder from your previous division
```

Answer (score 1):

For formatting, use Formatter.format(), giving it the dollars and cents as arguments and formatting it with the leading $ and exactly 2 digits for the cents (as suggested by someone above).  Since it's homework, i won't give away how to do this, but the javadocs should help:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this violates your rules (which sound really weird, but hay).  You could try

```
int totalChange = 1234;
DecimalFormat ourFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");
String totalString = ourFormat.format(totalChange / 100f);
System.out.println("Your change of " + totalString + " is as follows:");
```

Otherwise, I think you'd need to provide your own formatter.

Comment: Aside: Division of an integer (of reasonable size) by 100 into a float is lossless, right?

Comment: Besides, that's using a float.

Comment: Nothing is always "lossless" when using floats due to their inability to exactly represent integer values.  Also, that violates the rule about not working with floats.  Just because you don't name a float doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: @Eric J.: Not everything is lossy when using floats. It can exactly represent small integer values for example. But yes, this answer runs afoul of the self-imposed rule against floats.

Comment: @Thilo: Well yeah, up to 16,777,216 (2^24).  Depends on what "small" is :-)

Comment: Back when I worked in the financial industry we *never* used floating-point calculations because of the loss in precision due to inexact representation. Everything was done with integer arithmetic on values that represented 1/100th of a cent (100,000 hundredths == 1,000 cents == $10.00) and calculated rounding errors when dividing.

Comment: @StephenP fair point, just seemed weird to me, I think Erik's answer is great idea anyway